# PHP - need clarification on is_int() and while loop

Tags: php, loops, isinteger

I want to convert a decimal number to an integer by multiplying it by 10 until it gives me an integer.

Example:
0.2 should become 2 and 
0.004 should become 4

Here is my function

```
function make_integer($num){
    if (!is_int($num)){
        $temp = $num;
        while (!is_int($temp)){
            $temp *= 10;
        }
        return $temp;
    }
    return $num;
}
```

I want

```
make_integer(0.2) => 2
```

Shouldn't the function stop when $temp becomes an integer?
The function seems to be going in an infinite loop.

Could someone tell me why this isn't working please?

Comment: Print out `$temp` each time to see what the value is during the loop

Comment: it's not printing anything.  It just keeps loading with a blank screen.

Comment: funnily enough...I just ran this on my site.  no response in debug to check there either.  If you remove the middle loop you get a touch further but...

Comment: @Steve What do you mean the middle loop? There's only one loop in the function

Comment: @CodingStudent - yeah, I meant the middle as in structure, not 1,2,3 :) Has been a long day

Comment: A float datatype won't magically turn to an integer datatype when it's multiplied; so is_int() won't ever be true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short answer

This will solve your problem

```
function make_integer($num){
    if ((int)$num != $num){
        $temp = $num;
        while ((int)$temp != $temp){
            $temp *= 10;
        }
        return $temp;
    }
    return $num;
}
```

## Long Answer

The problem is that `is_int` does not test if your value is an integer or not. It will test if its *type* is an integer or not. So `is_int($var)` will do the same as if you ran `gettype($var) == 'integer'`.

Some basic tests:

```
is_int((int) 0.57); # returns true, because the type is an int.
is_int((float) 4); # returns false, because the type is a float
is_int(10 * 0.2); # returns false, because int*float will be typecasted to a float
```

To make your code work, and to test if a *value* is an integer, you should cast your variable to an integer and then test if it is still equal to the original variable, like this:

```
(int) $var == $var; # will return true if the value is int
```

To fix your code, substitute the `!is_int($num)` with `(int) $num != $num` and `!is_int($temp)` with `(int) $temp != $temp`, just like the code in the short answer above.

But, I can't resist to give an alternative solution to your problem. Personally, I would opt to use recursion for this problem. Like this:

```
function make_integer($num) {
    return (int)$num == $num ? $num : make_integer($num * 10);
}
```

Or if you dislike the ternary operator:

```
function make_integer($num) {
    if ((int)$num == $num)
        return $num; # We're all done!
    else
        return make_integer($num * 10); # Try to increase by 10
}
```

## Even longer answer

The type casting of php will take some time to learn. In general, PHP will allways try to type cast if it can. When you multiply an integer with a float, the result will be a float, even if it "looks" like an integer.

So try this code and pay special attention to the output:

```
$var = 0.03;
var_dump($var); # float(0.03)
var_dump(gettype($var)); # string(6) "double"
var_dump(is_int($var)); # bool(false)
```

Now, if you multiply by the integer 100, php will stick the float, as `<float>*<int>` multiplication allways will result in a float, regardless of the value.

```
$var *= 100; # (100 * 0.03)
var_dump($var); # float(3)
var_dump(gettype($var)); # string(6) "double"
var_dump(is_int($var)); # bool(false)
```

Note that the value is a natural number, but the type is still a float, and thus is_int will not return true.

To test if a actual *value* of a variable is indeed an integer, we will need to do our own little trick with manual typecasting.

```
$var = 2.33;
var_dump($var); # float(2.33)
$var = (int) $var;
var_dump($var); # int(2)
```

Note that when we tried to cast a float to an int the value changed. But if we try to cast a float that *is* an integer to an int, the value remains unaffected, only the *type* gets changed:

```
$var = 2.0;
var_dump($var); # float(2)
$var = (int) $var;
var_dump($var); # int(2)
```

And now, remember how `<int>*<float>` resulted in a float? PHP will work in the same way when you do comparisons. In php, `"2.0" == 2` will be `true` because of this automatic typecasting. So when you do `<int> == <float>` what really happens is `(float)<int> == <float>`.

So what happens if we do `(float)(int)0.3`. First we typecast 0.3 to int(0), then we typecast back to float(0). Obviously, `float(0) == float(0.3)` will be `false`. But `(float)(int)3.0` will be cast first to int(3) then to float(3), which was the same value we started with.

```
$var = 3.0;
var_dump($var); # float(3)
$var = (int) $var;
var_dump($var); # int(3)
$var = (float) $var;
var_dump($var); # float(3)
```

So if we do `(int) 3.0 == 3.0`, it will result in `(float)(int) 3.0 == 3.0` which is `true`.

So the way to test if a value is integer is to do

```
(int)$var == $var
```

Comment: Nice explanation/answer. I wanted to make a recursive function but php is a touch new to me. Kudos and thanks.

Comment: I think I'll stick to the recursive function, looks neater. Really good explanation. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### answer:

- $i=0.0004 ;
- gettype($i) == 'float'
- $i*= 10;
- gettype($i) == 'float'
- float != int

to resolve your problem, change the logic test.

- (int) $i == $i

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the prettiest but it works.

```
function make_int($num){

    //if it's not an int...
    if(!is_int($num)){

        //find out how many decimal places and store in a  variable
        $multiply =  strlen(substr(strrchr($num, "."), 1));

        //multiply the number by the power of the multiple.
            $num *= (pow (10,$multiply));

        return $num;
    }
}

make_int(0.004);
```

Comment: Thought about doing the same thing too. I guess i'm gonna have to go with this solution, thanks. Any ideas why my original function doesn't work?

Comment: I honestly don't know, I tagged php thinking someone might come along and explain.  Can only think that it's because of how it's being called.  Too tired to think :)
If it works, cick that amazing green button:)